# How do I simplify this algebraic fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

$$1-3(1/(3+x))+4(1/(3+x))^2$$
to
$$(4+3x+x^2)/(9+6x+x^2) ?$$

I can see the denominator $(9+6x+x^2)$ is a result of squaring out the brackets $(3+x)^2$ but I am stuck after that....

Comment: Try using Mathjax to write your question

Comment: Why do you want to simplify it? Is there any context?

Comment: Do you know how to "make common denominator"?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think I have to find the lowest common multiple of all the denominators in each term - so (x+3)^2.

Comment: @user376343 it was a composite function. Just because things are better simplified? That is the answer I have been given anyway, I got the first part which is right but they gave the simplified version..so in an exam I would be expected to give the simplified version.

Comment: Indeed. So what do you get when you make common denominator?